# electron.js | ipcRenderer and ipcMain cause white / blank screen

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuetify.js

I am creating a desktop app by using Electron, Vue + Vuetify but when I try to send something from rendererProcess to mainProcess with IPC, there becomes a white and blank screen, I do not know what caused this error.

// Main process

```
ipcMain.on('fileOps', (event, args) => {

});
```

// Renderer side

```
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer

const buttonClicked = () => {

    ipcRenderer.send("fileOps", "test");
}
module.exports = buttonClicked


import buttonClicked from "../renderer/file.js";

export default {
  mounted() {
          buttonClicked();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting nodeIntegration: true at main process.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a white screen, it's quite possible there was an error in your main process and your renderer process could not load (ie. why it is blank). Without console logs, it's hard to tell based on your question.

**Note**, by enabling `nodeIntegration`, you are opening up your app to security holes if it is loading remote content. I'd recommend using [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) to build your apps if you desire to use IPC to make secure apps. The framework is lightweight and has comments that should help you get started if you are new to electron apps.

Disclaimer: *I am the author of this template*